# distinct value of the element of the xml

Tags: asp.net, xml, xmlhttprequest, simplexml

How do i output distinct value of the **DateTime** element of the xml along with the number of time it occurs in the xml, all this using asp:treeview control.

xml file:

```
     <company>
         <Status>0</Status>
          <StatusDescription></StatusDescription>
           <FileList>
      <File>
        <FileID>120012</FileID>
        <DateTime>3/12/2011</DateTime>
      </File>
      <File>
        <FileID>120010</FileID>
        <DateTime>3/13/2011</DateTime>
      </File>
      <File>
        <FileID>120011</FileID>
        <DateTime>3/12/2011</DateTime>
      </File>
    </FileList>
</company>
```

output required:

3/12/2011 (2) 
3/13/2011 (1)

thanks, any help appreciated

Comment: Why you are use a treeview? Does File entry may have children files?

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of [Aggregation on asp:Treeview using xml datasource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969362/aggregation-on-asptreeview-using-xml-datasource)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Linq to XML to select the data you need from the XML document.

[LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)

Checkout this other Stackoverflow question which details how to select distinct values:

[Linq to XML Noob question - distinct and order by on attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021679/linq-to-xml-noob-question-distinct-and-order-by-on-attributes)

Using the response from your Linq query you can then generate your tree view nodes.

[Bind tree view control with XML using Linq](http://davepranav.wordpress.com/2009/10/27/bind-tree-view-control-with-xml-using-linq-part-12/)

[Working with XML Data Using LINQ, a TreeView, and a ListView](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020134102/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/042308-1.aspx)

Hope these help.

If you find this answer or any other answers useful, please mark then as answered.